# Go text template syntax highlighting in GoLand

Tags: go, go-templates, goland

GoLand has syntax support on Go html files with the file extension of `.gohtml`

So what about Go text files? Does GoLand support that as well? `.tmpl` is supported by vim-go but not GoLand.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/creating-and-registering-file-types.html Using the steps outlined in the link you should be able to configure Goland to support `.tmpl`.

Comment: Thanks, mkopriva, I figured it out by registering `.tmpl` file type to `go template file type`

Feel free to submit the answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 26):

As mkopriva has already hinted and you have described as well in the comments, you can go to `Preferences/Editor/File Types` and add your custom ending as `Registered pattern` to the Go Template. But imo the real game changer is that you can also set Go as `Template data language` there. This way even the Go syntax gets validated, not just the template syntax. It's still wonky, but definitly better than nothing.

[image]

Still, autoformatting does not work properly and can screw up your code. Therefore, you might also want to make sure the `Reformat code` in the commit dialog is unchecked. Same with `Optimize Imports` ... better keep it unchecked.

Comment: Actually, you can have everything: code highlighting, autocompletion, and formatting for BOTH html and template parts - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878314/jetbrains-goland-html-templates-formatting-and-code-completion

Comment: @IvanD I think that sadly doesn't hold true for all cases. For example, I had a go template (not html), and reformatting lines like `//Checks all {{$types}} out there` broke them ... and those broken lines were committed right after, to make things worse. I'ld be careful with that option in general and particulary with templates.

Comment: Right, I agree that it does not apply to purely text templates, my solution works for HTML templates only, correctly indenting both HTML and range loops

Answer (score 2):

there are two parts to this answer to get both html highlighting and go template highlighting

1. go template highlighting:

settings > editor > file types > select `Go template files` from the list > update pattern to the file ending you use for your go templates. I used `*.go.html`

2. html highlighting

settings > template data languages > project language (dropdown at the top) > set to html

now you have both html highlighting and go template completion